# Android: Limiting app to certain screensizes, cannot prevent install

Tags: android, android-screen-support

New question:
I want to limit the application for devices between 4.3" and 5", is it not possible to be that specific?
It seems the attributes used to do that are not used by Google play...

Old question (answered):
I have beeen looking at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

But if I use for example:
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
and set all to false I can still install the app but then it mysteriously crashes. I do not want it to install in the first place...

I want to support 4.3" to 5", how would I do that? or is that to specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you should do. If you are adding the app to Google Play, you don't have to limit the screen size in the Manifest .xml file, You simply just have to go to your App Developer Console, And give the Screen Sizes or the Phone Devices you want to allow to access the app from the Google Play download Session(White-Listing). If the phone u have white-listed is not in your list, the user won't be able to install your app from google play. I hope this helps, feel free to ask more questions

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong on this, but setting `android:smallScreens="false"` on your Manifest file will only prevent the app from being installed from external sources with that particular feature (the small screen), but not prevent it from installing on a development phone as in running it from Eclipse/AndroidStudio to your device.

Quoting the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html):

> An application that does not support small screens will not be
>   available for small screen           devices from external services
>   (such as Google Play), because there is little the platform can do to
>   make such an application work on a smaller screen.